# Calculating TSS on streaming data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math, moving-average

TSS is calculated as `(x - mean) **2`  and it is easy to calculate if all of the data is readily available to you. But in my case, the data is streaming continuously and I need to calculate moving TSS on this data. For example, let's say that the whole data is `x=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])`. But this data is streaming in batches, like this:

```
batch1: [1, 2, 3]
batch2: [4, 5, 6, 7]
batch3: [8, 9, 10]
```

How can I calculate the moving TSS in this case? Any logical explanation along with the solution will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TSS can be split into two terms, each of which can easily be calculated incrementally:

TSS = sum[ ( X - sum[X]/N )<sup>2</sup> ]

= sum[ X<sup>2</sup> - 2X*sum[X]/N + sum[X]<sup>2</sup>/N<sup>2</sup> ]

= sum[X<sup>2</sup>] - 2sum[X]<sup>2</sup>/N + sum[X]<sup>2</sup>/N

= sum[X<sup>2</sup>] - sum[X]<sup>2</sup>/N

You only need to maintain running totals of X and X<sup>2</sup>, along with a count N of how many samples you've seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could add each batch to a cumulative array in each step:

```
cum_array = numpy.concatenate((cum_array, batch))
```

Then calculate TSS as:

```
tss = (cum_array - numpy.mean(cum_array))**2
```

which would rewrite the TSS array each time.  If you simply wanted to add the newly calculated values, you'd need something like:

```
cum_array = numpy.concatenate((cum_array, batch))
tss = numpy.concatenate((tss, numpy.zeros_like(batch)))
tss[-batch_len:] = (cum_array[-batch_len:] - numpy.mean(cum_array))**2
```

EDIT: if you only want a value for TSS at the end of each batch you could do:

```
running_total += numpy.sum(batch)
N += len(batch)
tss = (batch[-1] - running_total/N)**2
```

Comment: Thanks for the  answer. I know I can do that but I don't want to because the data is literally huge